# I have a problem with Azure DevOps on commiting changes

Tags: azure, devops, commit

I have an Azure DevOps solution.
In that solution I have two projects, both with TFS.
One of the project is a Blazor WebServer application and the other is a WindForm application.

On both solutions i have the Source Control Explorer open, where I can see both DevOps projects in each Visual Studio solutions.

In the Blazor solutions I connect to the DevOps project for that and in the Winform solution I connect to that.
So far so good.

The problem occurs when I fx. in the Winform solution commit changes, it works fine for that solution. But when I then go to my Blazor soliution I can no longer commit even if I now there was changes. Somehow the commit in one solution also commit changes in the other solution.

How can I avoid that?

I only tried to make sure to connect to the correct project in my solutions.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error.
it is just that when I commit changes in one of the projects it also commit changes in the other project. And I do not wan't that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Both project was in the same workspace in Visual Studio.
As soon as they each got their own it seem to work.